# Plus five or plus ten?

Tags: support, reputation, up-votes

On another meta question, I mentioned one that I wrote long before that had several up votes.  I was asked to link to it.  Not long after, it got two more.  I guess people followed the link and liked it.  Not important.

But what I don't get is the rationale for why one up vote adds five points and another the same day adds ten.

Comment: Question vs answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When that user upvoted the answer, you got +10. When they upvoted the question, you got +5.

For reference, check out this post: [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/321647) All the following is quoted verbatim from there:

> #### You gain reputation when:
>
> - one of your questions is voted *up/useful*: **+5**
> - one of your answers is voted *up/useful*: **+10**
> - one of your answers becomes *accepted*: **+15**
> - you *accept* an answer written by someone else to one of your own questions: **+2**
> - a downvote on one of your questions or answers is removed: **+2**
> - you [suggest an edit and it is accepted][11]: **+2** (up to a total of +1000 per user)
> - you remove a downvote from an answer: **+1**
> - an answer you downvoted is removed: **+1**
> - one of your answers is awarded a bounty by the user offering the bounty: **+full bounty amount**
> - one of your answers is awarded a bounty automatically: **+½ of the bounty amount** (see [bounty
>   FAQ](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067)
>   for details)
> - you *associate accounts* of two or more Stack Exchange network sites, and at least one of those accounts already has 200 or more
>   reputation: **+100** on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per
>   site)
>
> #### You lose reputation when:
>
> - one of your questions or answers is voted *down/not useful*: **−2**
> - a post where you had successfully *suggested an edit* has been *deleted* (reputation page shows the cause as "*removed*"): **-2**
> - the account of *a user who was the final approver of a suggested edit you made* [has been
>   deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311413) (reputation page
>   shows the cause as "*User was removed*"): **-2**
> - you vote an answer *down/not useful*: **−1**
> - an upvote on one of your questions is removed: **−5**
> - an upvote on one of your answers is removed: **−10**
> - one of your *accepted* answers loses *accepted* status: **−15**
> - you *unaccept* an answer written by someone else to one of your own questions: **-2**
> - you place a bounty on a question: **−full bounty amount**
> - one of your posts receives 6 [spam][12] or [*"it is not welcome in our community"* flags][13] (formerly known as *offensive* flags):
>   **−100**

Comment: Oh,I see.  I knew a lot of that, but I didn't know questions had different value than answers.  I think most of that 1262 was from that specific question.  Seems people really like it for some reason.

Comment: @WGroleau Yeah that question is interesting. Your rep comes from many different posts, though. Maybe you just haven't been paying a lot of attention to reputation, which is actually a good thing.

Comment: Agreed.  If I have to ask, I don't have the knowledge to judge between contradicting answers.  Rep is supposed to help me there.  The more it gets treated as some kind of personal entitlement that we (in general) fight for, the less useful it becomes.